# How to increment value from FutureBuilder Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How to increment value? in Flutter, I need to increment the value from 1 - 3 without adding firestore `data 1, 2, 3` in it, any help is highly appreciated. This is my code and kindly check image below for reference. Thank you

```
  return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
  future: users.doc(widget.documentId).get(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){

      Map<String, dynamic> data = {};
      data = snapshot.data?.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      
      increment++;

      return Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.red[200],
                width: 50,
                child: Text(
                    increment.toString(), //<- increment this value 
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 2.7,
                    )
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.green[200],
                width: 270,
                child: Text(
                  data['fullName'],
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 3.06,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        Divider(thickness: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * .27),
        ],
      );
    }
    Text("Loading.."),
  },
);
```

[image]

Comment: did you try doing increment = increment + 1;

Comment: `future: users.doc(widget.documentId).get(),`, uh, No, just no.  Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this you will index.

```
body: FutureBuilder<List<String>?>(
  future: getData(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData &&
        snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Text(snapshot.data?[index] ?? "got null");
        },
      );
    }

    /// handles others as you did on question
    else {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Permission to admin or moderator, kindly delete this question, thanks to @Mahesh answer but I rather used StreamBuilder to make this work, and its now working fine. Thank you. Kindly close or delete this thread